# Python: Trouble sorting only some columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe and only want to sort the first three columns in my dataframe in a specific order. The order of the rest of the columns does not matter. I have 40 columns in total.

This thread had a solution but it doesn't seem to work for me: [how to sort only some of the columns in a data frame in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579871/how-to-sort-only-some-of-the-columns-in-a-data-frame-in-pandas)

The solution in the link above recommends tackling this problem in three steps by using `reindex` in the following way:

```
preordered = list('xyz')
new_order = preordered + list(df.columns - preordered)
df.reindex(columns=new_order)
```

In my case, the name of the three columns I want as first, second and third column are the following: `in_Code`, `in_Name`, and `Code` - in that specific order.

Since `list()` can only take on one argument, I used `preordered=list(['in_Code','in_Name','Code'])` for the first step.

Yet the second step, `new_order=preordered + list(df.columns - preordered)` gives me a `TypeError: cannot perform __sub__ with this index type: Index`.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,(10,6)), columns=[*'ABWXYZ'])

orderedCols = ['Z','Y','W']
nonOrderedCols = [i for i in df.columns if i not in orderedCols]

nonOrderedCols
# ['A', 'B', 'X']

orderedCols
# ['Z', 'Y', 'W']

df.reindex(orderedCols + nonOrderedCols, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    Z   Y   W   A   B   X
0  29  61  65  17  95  59
1  87   2  98   4  79  85
2  53  45   2  77  49  81
3  72  47  58  53  22  24
4  74  66  50  93  29  71
5  23  94  70  38  11  94
6  54  60   7  29   3  33
7  31   1  67  80  68  57
8  99  50  79  28  49  52
9  73  46  77  17  47  93
```

Note: You can also use `nonOrderedCols = df.columns[~df.columns.isin(orderedCols)]`

Comment: This looks promising but the 'or' in your post is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you would use

```
 df.sort_values(by=['in_Code','in_Name','Code'])
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I get an error 'Check for Duplicates'. Is this sorting the values in the three columns, rather than the columns themselves? I would like the columns sorted, don't really care about the values.